# Nodejs Canvas module loads at command line but will not load in nssm service

Tags: node.js, node-canvas, nssm

When running a node app using the nssm service manager, the canvas module will not load, but when running the app from the command line it does.

The service is running in win7/32 bits, node version is 10.16 and canvas version 2.5.

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.

\\?\C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\canvas\lib\bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
(node:7820) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due 
to security and usability issues
```